# Spring : How to give properties file to Java.exe

Tags: spring, properties, properties-file

I am using Spring to develop a Java application. I have stored certain properties in a properties file, which is packaged as a JAR. The properties are read in code using @Value annotation. Now when i deploy the JAR i want to supply new values for some of these properties. I know that we can give the new property value as "-Dproperty-name=property-value". But is there a way to give a new property file itself as input which has many properties to be overridden together?

Thanks
Chenbaga

Answer (score 0):

You can have a number of different property files and then load then with a specific system parameter.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/app.properties", "file:/${configLocation}/app.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)

public class AppConfig {
```

Add your default app.properties to /src/resources/app.properties

Then when you start your JVM you can override with

```
-DconfigLocation=/home/config
```

If the configLocation is present it will first pick up the default properties, then override then with the ones from the file.  If the system parameter is not present it will not file the file and use the defaults.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html for more examples

Comment: Thanks Essec. This is what i am doing now. But i need to overwrite some of these property values when i execute the JAR. I want to put all these properties in a file, and give that file as input to JVM, instead of giving each property as -D when executing JAR.

Comment: @ChenbagaMurugan I didn't understand your question, look at the answer now.  The are also plenty of examples of this on the spring link.